Nextjs: The requested resource isn't a valid image | received text/html;charset=utf-8 for external source
I'm using one API to get image sources and some of them are of type text/html;charset=utf-8, the rest are image/pngs and they're working fine.
For text/html I'm getting errors on both server and client:
Client:
http://localhost:3000/_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Ford-mirror.magiceden.dev%2Fcontent%2F4b31771df21656d2a77e6fa18720a6dd94b04510b9065a7c67250d5c89ad2079i469&w=256&q=75 400 (Bad Request)

Server:
 ⨯ The requested resource isn't a valid image for https://ord-mirror.magiceden.dev/content/deff9507e7dfd068b6b2facf38df83c6e34ba58e164d6351e64c390f89b06fc1i51 received text/html;charset=utf-8

Found the same issue on github, but it seemed to be fixed by changing docker config, but I'm not using Docker
https://github.com/stonith404/pingvin-share/issues/262
Also saw another issue, where downgrading nextjs version helped, but can't find it rn
replacing <Image /> with <iframe> works, but it takes too long to load them

provide some of working and non-working urls
